# Uncertainties on overriding the get method of Hashmap collection

Tags: java, collections

I have a `getMailBox` method which returns a `HashMap` obtained by grouping values from a `List<E>`.

I need to override the get method so it doesn't return null if the key is not found and return an empty `List<T>`.

When I do this, everything works and a map with an overridden method is returned

```
    public Map<String, List<T>> getMailBox() {

    Map<String, List<T>> tempMap = new HashMap<>() {
        @Override
        public List<T> get(Object key) {
            Optional<List<T>> optional = Optional.ofNullable(super.get(key));
            return optional.orElse(Collections.emptyList());
        }
    };

    Map<String, List<T>> map = list.stream()
            .collect(
                    java.util.stream.Collectors
                            .groupingBy(
                                    Sendable::getTo,
                                    java.util.stream.Collectors
                                            .mapping(
                                                    Sendable::getContent,
                                                    java.util.stream.Collectors
                                                    .toList())));
    tempMap.putAll(map);

    return tempMap;
```

If I do this instead, it returns a map with a method not overridden and returns null if the key is not found.

```
public static class MailService<T> implements Consumer<Sendable <T>> {

        private final List<Sendable<T>> list = new ArrayList<>();

        public Map<String, List<T>> getMailBox() {

            Map<String, List<T>> map = new HashMap<>() {
                @Override
                public List<T> get(Object key) {
                    Optional<List<T>> optional = Optional.ofNullable(super.get(key));
                    return optional.orElse(Collections.emptyList());
                }
            };

            map = list.stream().collect(
                          java.util.stream.Collectors
                                   .groupingBy(
                                            Sendable::getTo,
                                            java.util.stream.Collectors
                                                    .mapping(Sendable::getContent,
                                                           java.util.stream.Collectors
                                                                   .toList())));
            return map;
        }
```

Why doesn't the second version return a `Map` with the overridden method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity's sake let's pretend you actually created a class that inherits from `HashMap` and you overrode the `get` method like you did. Let's call this class `MutatedHashMap`.

In your first example `tempMap` is a `MutatedHashMap`, then you do your stuff in another map called `map` and add its elements to `tempMap`. Everything works fine.

In your second example you define `map` as a `MutatedHashMap`, but then you reassign another value to `map` with those stream operations, which of course don't return a `MutatedHashMap`, but whatever `collect` returns. Therefore the returned object won't have your modified `get` method because `map` is no longer a `MutatedHashMap`.